# Errors were encountered while processing: initramfs-tools linux-firmware Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Whenever i run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

i get this error

```
> Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
Warning: /sbin/fsck.ext4 doesn't exist, can't install to initramfs, ignoring.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
Warning: /sbin/fsck.ext4 doesn't exist, can't install to initramfs, ignoring.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-firmware
```

after some googling i found out it has something to do with `/boot` partition being full but apparently it's not , here's the result of `dh -f`  :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda9        83G   17G   62G  22% /
tmpfs           7.8G  105M  7.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop3      196M  196M     0 100% /snap/vlc/555
/dev/loop0       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/970
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/9
/dev/loop5       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/941
/dev/loop6      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/loop27      89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop29     239M  239M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/26
/dev/loop26     203M  203M     0 100% /snap/vlc/768
/dev/sda1       256M   35M  222M  14% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   64K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

i also can't install/update/upgrade any package or use dpkg and apt-get.
 also i deleted old kernels.
it seems like an infinite loop of errors and they all take me back to 
that error

```
Errors were encountered while processing:  
initramfs-tools  
linux-firmware
```

Output of `apt policy e2fsprogs libext2fs2`

```
e2fsprogs:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.44.1-1
  Version table:
     1.44.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1.42.13-1ubuntu1 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libext2fs2:
  Installed: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.44.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these two lines of your output, I conclude that the package `e2fsprogs` is missing or corrupted:

```
Warning: /sbin/fsck.ext4 doesn't exist, can't install to initramfs, ignoring.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
```

The first line directly says `/sbin/fsck.ext4` is missing, which is a file provided by that package I mentioned. Examining the failing script mentioned in the second line, it turns out that this one requires `/sbin/dumpe2fs`, which is provided by the same package too.

To fix the issue, you should (re?)install `e2fsprogs` by running:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall e2fsprogs
```

The fact that the package containing the failing `fixrtc` initramfs hook (`initramfs-tools-core`) does not depend on the seemingly required `e2fsprogs` package though should probably be considered as a bug. [I have reported it on Launchpad here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1831747)

---

**Update:**

As `e2fsprogs` refuses to install because it conflicts with an incompatible version of `libext2fs2` that you have installed from an unknown and no longer available source, we have to downgrade that other package back to the supported version in the process too:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall e2fsprogs libext2fs2=1.44.1-1
```

Comment: trying to reinstall e2fsprogs gives me this error `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` , and attempting to install the missing dependencies takes me back to this 
`Errors were encountered while processing: linux-firmware initramfs-tools E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the full output? Did it successfully install `e2fsprogs` during that or did it not even try?

Comment: `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 e2fsprogs : PreDepends: libext2fs2 (= 1.44.1-1) but 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
             Recommends: e2fsprogs-l10n but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Aha, we're getting closer to the root of the problem. Can you show the output of `apt policy e2fsprogs libext2fs2`? Also *please* edit your question to add important information. Comments might get lost and can not be formatted properly.

Comment: @AlyaGomaa Thank you. Please see my updated answer. You got a newer, incompatible version of that other library from somewhere, which is now blocking (and probably was the original cause why it got uninstalled in the first place) `e2fsprogs`. You can downgrade it back to the original, supported version by specifying the exact version in the install command with an =.

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: Cool. Please consider accepting the answer to mark your question as solved, if the proposed solution was actually successful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the text in your terminal.  Mine said it couldn't create a certain vmlinuz file so I manually created it in the directory it indicated.  Then I was able to reinstall e2fsprogs and it worked fine.